# Google Closure requires RequestFilter and BlockingResponse types during chrome extension compiling. How to create such types?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-closure-compiler

I have an issue while compiling **chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener** code line in the Google Closure Compiler.

I took the code example from CatBlock extension in samples https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#12a7bf1490a26359eadf10917e37c5b9 and add some compiler parameters:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name extension.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @externs_url http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/git/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(info) {
    console.log("Cat intercepted: " + info.url);
    // Redirect the lolcal request to a random loldog URL.
    var i = Math.round(Math.random() * loldogs.length);
    return {redirectUrl: loldogs[i]};
},
// filters
{
    urls: ["https://i.chzbgr.com/*"],
    types: ["image"]
},
// extraInfoSpec
["blocking"]);
```

Closure Compiler raises two JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH warnings and requires **BlockingResponse** and **RequestFilter** types.
According to API Reference https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html both of them are objects, but why does compiler refuse objects that I pass?

I've looked into chrome_extensions.js and it has own constructors for BlockingResponse and RequestFilter types, but browser doesn't have them.

I've also tried to assign this objects to variables and define types using annotations.

```
/** @type {!BlockingResponse} response */
var response = {redirectUrl: loldogs[i]};

/** @type {!RequestFilter} filter */
var filter= {urls: ["https://i.chzbgr.com/*"], types: ["image"]};
```

This didn't help and seems like it’s not the proper way.

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't really a problem, they are just warnings. My use of `webRequest` does the same thing. Just ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the warnings, you'd need to type cast your return values:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name extension.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @externs_url http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/git/contrib/externs/chrome_extensions.js
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {   
    console.log("Cat intercepted: " + info.url);
    // Redirect the lolcal request to a random loldog URL.
    var i = Math.round(Math.random() * loldogs.length);
    return /** @type {!BlockingResponse} */ ({redirectUrl: loldogs[i]});
},
// filters
/** @type {!RequestFilter} */ 
({
    urls: ["https://i.chzbgr.com/*"],
    types: ["image"]
}),
// extraInfoSpec
["blocking"]);
```

*note the extra parenthesis*

With this usage, it would be better if the extern specified a return type of `BlockingResponse|Object.<string,*>`, but we'd need to file an issue in the closure-compiler project for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’ve submitted an issue to closure-compiler team - https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/issues/detail?id=956